# Encryption and improvement of Postgres performance

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption, database-performance

I'm a bachelor student currently doing an internship in a small company and have been asked to find how encryption of certain data within a database could be achieved, preferably without having to change the scripts that are already accessing to the database. I've been digging into two directions, respectively using triggers/view with the built-in encryption functions of PostgreSQL to encrypt/decrypt data, and implementing a base datatype with the encryption logic in the input and output functions.

After that, I've been running a little script to see how much time the database was taking with simple insert and select on simple tables in PostgreSQL and MySQL (my reference because the company is currently using it) and on tables with my solutions. The result that surprised me was the huge difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL speed, up to 10 times slower on a thousand select.

I understand that the amount of data is very small and that the database has not been tuned, so is it possible to get at least equal performances than with MySQL? I don't have much information about the running database, but from what I've read the performances of a database are heavily dependent on the profile (hardware, organization of data, type of query). Is there some typical cases where PostgreSQL outperforms MySQL? Apart from this, is there something inherently wrong with these solutions? I still have to design the key distribution system for the encryption/decryption but I was told to let that on the side for the moment.

Edit: To test the database I'm using bash script with psql and mysql command-line tool, as well as time stamp to evaluate the time taken by some operations (1 insert of 1000 rows and 1000 insert of 1 row, same for select statement).

Edit2: so concerning encryption I had two implementation ideas.

- **Create a view data on each table data_encrypted**

like

```
CREATE VIEW data AS
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(nom::bytea, 'Password'),id
    FROM data_encrypt;
```

and a set of triggers that apply on the view data for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE query like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION encrypt_nom() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
BEGIN
    UPDATE data_encrypt SET nom = (pgp_sym_encrypt(NEW.nom,'Password'))WHERE id=NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END; 
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_encrypt INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON data FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE encrypt_nom();
```

So the idea is to use the pgp_sym_encrypt/decrypt (AES with salt) functions to transparently encrypt/decrypt from data_encrypt when the user query on the view data.

reference to the [pgcrypto module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgcrypto.html)

- **Create a crypting datatype**

As I said for this I implement the Encryption/Decryption function into the input/output functions described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xtypes.html)

Since it's C code I planned to use an open library like openaes

But again I was asked to not consider the key allocation for the moment, only the feasibility of encryption, which could eventually be a big block in the future(if for one reason or another it's not possible to run an external software from these methods).

For the data to encrypt I have to admit that I'm a bit in the fog: no access to the database and the only thing I was told is that it's running on Mysql with InnoDB and that it's accessed through local host. doesn't help much. I suppose things like sensitive personal data from customers or employee.

Comment: How do you test? Without this information it's impossible to tell if MySQL is really faster than PostgreSQL. And don't forget MySQL has an internal connection pool, PostgreSQL needs an external one, like pgBouncer or pgPool.

Comment: @FrankHeikens , I edited my post. I suppose it's not a very good way to test it. Is there some methods that are suited to compare two different database systems?

Comment: What are the requirements for your system? It looks like your test involves only one database connection and no concurrency. What type of MySQL-engine do you use? MyISAM is fast for a single request, but painfully slow on concurrency. And very dangerous, you could loose all data at any moment. Without testing for all requirements, it's difficult to help you. FYI: PostgreSQL can be extremely fast and much faster than MySQL on the same workload. Most of the performance depends on you, how you organize the workload.

Comment: What type of encryption are you using? Are you encrypting the data using a function while inserting? If so, can you give an example. Are you encrypting multiple columns or large data? We need some examples to analyze what is going on.

Comment: @JoeLove I edited my post, but I don't know if it will help so much. But I also realized that my simulation is not good so I will come back with more accurate info from client load emulators and, i hope, about the specificity of the company database.

Comment: I will say that when using a "where" clause, it's much more efficient to compare the "encrypted" data with the "encrypted" input data. here's a pseudo example:
"where password = encrypt('somepassword',key)"
instead of "where decrypt(pssword',key) = 'somepassword'"